# Simple CSS transitions doesnt work on browsers but in phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

I cant see my mistake in this test of a facebook style menu with bootstrap.
The transition of the sidemenu after press the button work perfectly when I wrap it for android with phonegap(in webview), but seems they dont work on any browser...

Here you have the folders in google drive: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzJGOFi8-v0YdmVWYldOZUhBcXc&usp=sharing

Here you can access the result, hosted on google drive, make the window small to check it: https://googledrive.com/host/0BzJGOFi8-v0YdmVWYldOZUhBcXc/index.html

Thankyou, hope you can give me some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.row-offcanvas needs an initial "Left" value of zero to animate from.

Unrelated, but I also noticed some errors about viewing the page via HTTPS (secure connection), but using included files from none secure places.

Comment: Thankyou so much. Was that. About the other error, are the web-fonts from google, so nothing to worry about for a test hehe.